# Using the cryptography library, I am unsure exactly how to decrypt the data properly without an error

Tags: python

I'm in the middle of taking a basic AP Computer Science class on Python, I am working on a project that is able to encrypt a password with salt and then decrypt it using the key. I experienced the error below, which was shown when I attempted to start the decryption process of a password using various cryptography libraries

Error I recieved:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 104, in <module>
    everything()
  File "main.py", line 96, in everything
    f = Fernet(passCrypt) # Value of an actual key is given.
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'passCrypt' referenced before assignment
```

Encryption Process

```
password = input("Enter your password: ")
      pass_Encoded = password.encode()
      salt = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(16))
      kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
      )
      key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(pass_Encoded))
      clearConsole()
      print("The key is: ", key)
      x = Fernet(key)
      passCrypt = x.encrypt(pass_Encoded)
      print("The encrypted pass is: ", passCrypt)
```

Decryption Process

```
else:
    x = Fernet(passCrypt) # Value of an actual key is given.
    decrypted_data = x.decrypt(passCrypt)
    print("After decryption : ", decrypted_data.decode())
```

Ignore the "else:" it's just because I have a selection between 1 and 2 to register a key and decrypt it. I'm sure I'm doing this completely incorrectly especially with the salt so some assistance would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Your decrypt function should be able to handle the salt ? what the documentation of the cryptography lib say about that ?

Comment: The error states that you are using a variable `passCrypt` before it's been assigned. I'm assuming you define it in the if statement whose else statement is the one you've pasted above.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the IF statement, do I need to do something to bring it down to the else statement.

Comment: Also, can you link the documentation to decrypt with a salt? I can't really find the propper article, thanks.

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post [mre].

Comment: _I'm sure I'm doing this completely incorrectly especially with the salt so some assistance would be very helpful._ this expands the scope of the question, which is about the `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: *Ignore the else*: no, can't do that, because that's exactly what the problem is. The `else`-clause expects `passCrypt` to exist, but that only gets bound in the `if`-clause, so if the  `else`-clause fires instead, the variable doesn’t get defined.